# Caused by android too large exception (data parcel 2076400 bytes)

Tags: android, exception, large-data

Trying too pass hash map data using intent extras to another activity gives transaction too large exception error.(data parcel 2076400 bytes)

this is code for passing map data to another activity which receives error.

```
if {

    mCountDownTimer =   new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

    public void onFinish() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, 
        ShowImagesActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("hashMap", map);
        startActivity(intent);
        if(Splash.Getproduct ==null) {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) 
             mInterstitialAd.show();
       }.start();
    }
}
```

How to avoid this and send this data to another activity.

Comment: there is a limit of data size in the Intent. Looks like you have reached it. Don't use Intent for large data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a limit to the amount of data that you can send via intents.
Its is 1 MB. Ideally you should only be sending a few KB worth of data through intents.

Your data size is around 2 MB which exceeds this limit.
If you intent to pass this much data, you an as well persist this in a database or in an inmemory data store.

*The Binder transaction buffer has a limited fixed size, currently 1MB, which is shared by all transactions in progress for the process. Since this limit is at the process level rather than at the per activity level, these transactions include all binder transactions in the app such as onSaveInstanceState, startActivity and any interaction with the system. When the size limit is exceeded, a TransactionTooLargeException is thrown.*

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles